# Prevent the connectors from being damaged by water infiltration

Tags: connector, waterproof

In my aquarium driven by an Arduino, I connected all the internal peripherals to the tank (such as lighting, flow sensors, thermometers, PH) with [D-SUB](https://it.farnell.com/productimages/standard/en_US/98AH3257-40.jpg), [RCA](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hc9c76b06dae14b10997f562e37f18ceaD.jpg) and [3.5 mm stereo jack connectors](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/0MEAAOSwZuJkEP5R/s-l400.jpg).

Do you know of a way to prevent the water from capillarity going up the electrical wires and damaging the connectors?

Until now I replaced the connectors every six months, but I'd like to find a permanent solution to the problem!

Comment: Buy a connector that is water proof and can be submerged so you need to change it only once. Also cables or wires that have insulation made of water proof material that can be submerged will keep the water from seeping in through insulation and damaging the copper wires. I don't know what to answer really, can you be more specific what you are after?

Comment: The connectors are out of the water about a meter from the aquarium, so any waterproof connectors would be useless. my problem is that, as happens with the sap of the plants, the water goes up the electrical wires ending up in the connectors making them rust.

Comment: See if you can find low voltage cable (telephone, network, sprinkler) meant for “direct burial”. Some have silicone grease inside the sheath to resist water intrusion and creep.

Comment: @Pinguto: Are they immersed? Or only in humid air?

Comment: @MarkLeavitt I'm using phone cables and CAT5 ethernet cables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google "water blocked cable". These are cables designed to prevent water from traveling through the cable and are used in sonar systems as well as aquariums and other applications requiring immersed cables. They work by having a filler material between the cable conductors to fill up the empty volume and prevent water creepage.

Comment: Where can I buy them? Do you have any amazon, ebay or aliexpress links? I did a short search to no avail.

Comment: Here is a link to Belden: https://www.belden.com/blogs/waterblocking but there are others using that google term.

Answer (score 2):

Use sealed circular connectors. [Cables with sealed circular connectors for LED lighting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LCV8DXQ) are particularly common and inexpensive.

Comment: They are not made to be immersed. After all IP65 means: Protected against low pressure jets of water from all directions, limited ingress permitted.

Comment: Did OP say that they are immersed? I don't see it.

Comment: No, the connectors are not immersed: the problem is that the water goes up the electric cable under the sheath thus ending up in the connectors outside the aquarium.

Comment: In that case, IP65 _is_ sufficient.